# Parsing the link returned by CloudExport

Tags: head

Consider

> [image]

Is there a way to make a function `justLink` that parses a `CloudObject[<link>]` and returns just the string denoting the link (i.e., removes the `CloudObject` head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have look how is a [`CloudObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObject.html) represented internally, using [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html)

```
FullForm@CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/28cb3105-23a4-419d-9c26-b7badc8517f6"]
(* CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/28cb3105-23a4-419d-9c26-b7badc8517f6"] *)
```

Ok, it's just a head and a string, so using [`First`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) should suffice.

```
First@CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/28cb3105-23a4-419d-9c26-b7badc8517f6"]
(* https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/28cb3105-23a4-419d-9c26-b7badc8517f6 *)
```